# How to save BitmapImage via SaveFileDialog from WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, savefiledialog

The way I try implement it via standart Windows.Forms (to get valide DialogResult.OK)

```
            System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog dlg = new System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog();
            dlg.FileName = "Document"; // Default file name
           // dlg.DefaultExt = ".jpg"; // Default file extension
            dlg.Filter = "JPeg Image|*.jpg|Bitmap Image|*.bmp|Gif Image|*.gif";
            if(dlg.ShowDialog()== System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) 
if (dlg.DialogResult.HasValue && splashDialog.DialogResult.Value)
            {
              string fName = dlg.FileName; 
              if (dlg.FileName != "")
              {
                 System.IO.Stream fileStream = (System.IO.FileStream)dlg.OpenFile(); 

                  fileStream.Close();
               }
             }
```

This is using Windows forms but it saves blank image((

Comment: You're just opening and closing the file, you never write the image in it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder(); // Or PngBitmapEncoder, or whichever encoder you want
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(yourImage));
using (var stream = dlg.OpenFile())
{
    encoder.Save(stream);
}
```

BTW, there is a `SaveFileDialog` in WPF too, you don't have to use the one from Windows Forms

Comment: Just use `Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog` instead of `System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog`

Answer (score 0):

For WPF code will be like :

```
Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
dlg.FileName = "Document";             
dlg.Filter = "JPeg Image|*.jpg|Bitmap Image|*.bmp|Gif Image|*.gif";
if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder(); // Or PngBitmapEncoder, or whichever encoder you want
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bi));
    using (var stream = dlg.OpenFile())
    {
         encoder.Save(stream);
    }
}
```

Here bi is the BitmapImage